# Using Lists with Many-to-Many relationship in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core-mvc, many-to-many, entity-framework-core

So i'm developing a basic project which uses Entity Framework Core to create a database that fetches information from TMDB based on whatever movie I enter to try and understand the whole thing better.

I've been stuck for a while trying to implement a Many-to-Many relationship between my Movie and Studio models.

Movies can have many studios attributed to them, but there are also many movies that will be connected to the studios, so it's the clear relationship to use.
    Below are snippets from those models:

```
public class Movies
{
    [Key]
    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MovieStudios> MovieStudios { get; set; } = new List<MovieStudios>();
}
public class Studios
{
    [Key]
    public int StudioID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MovieStudios> MovieStudios { get; set; } = new List<MovieStudios>();
}
```

And here is the join table that i've got

```
public class MovieStudios
{
    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public Movies Movie { get; set; }
    public int StudioID { get; set; }
    public Studios Studio { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my DbContext class:
        public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet TblMovies { get; set; }
        public DbSet TblStudios { get; set; }

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder option)
    {
        option.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Database=ServerDatabase ; Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MovieStudios>()
            .HasKey(bc => new { bc.MovieID, bc.StudioID });
    }
}
```

What I want to do, in one of my services, is return List so that I can link these studios to the movie in question when a movie is added to the database, but i'm just completely lost as for what to do. Sorry if this is a noob question, of if this is too long, just feel completely lost!

EDIT:
To be more specific, I pass through the TMDB id of a film to a service i've created that returns a list of the ids of the films production studios e.g.('46226', '6735'), which is then saved in my database and also returns the index number of my Studio database so that it can be added to my film. ('1', '4', '6'). I've stored this as a List and am stuck as to how I can add these studio ids to the film i'm trying to add to the database. All examples i've seen don't really address what i'm trying to do. I'm trying to add Many studios to the one film.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do it is this one:

```
// define composite key for MovieStudios
modelBuilder
    .Entity<MovieStudios>()
    .HasKey(ct => new {ct.MovieId, ct.StudioId});

// setup one-to-many relationship MovieStudios-Movies
modelBuilder.Entity<MovieStudios>()
    .HasOne(movieStudio => movieStudio.Movie)
    .WithMany(movie => movie.MovieStudios)
    .HasForeignKey(movieStudio => movieStudio.MovieId);

// setup one-to-many relationship MovieStudios-Studios
modelBuilder.Entity<MovieStudios>()
    .HasOne(movieStudio => movieStudio.Studio)
    .WithMany(studio => studio.MovieStudios)
    .HasForeignKey(movieStudio => movieStudio.StudioId);
```

A `many-to-many` relationship between `Movies` and `Studios` is equivalent to two `one-to-many` relationships between `MovieStudios` (relationship table) and `Movies` and `Studios` respectively.

**Edit:**

You can add movies to a studio like this:

```
public async Task AddMoviesToStudioAsync(List<Movie> movies, int studioId) 
{
    var movieStudiosList
        = movies.Select(
            movie => new MovieStudios
            {
                MovieId = movie.Id, 
                StudioId = studioId
            })
            .ToList();

    await DbContext.Set<MovieStudios>().AddRangeAsync(movieStudiosList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering - but i'm looking for how to add movies to a studio if I had multiple studio id's in a List<Studio> so that I can have multiple studio ids under the one movie. Would I just add the List in place of the int studioId, or would I loop through and run the method for the length of my List of Studio ids?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have two lists: `List<Movie>` and `List<Studio>` and you want to add all those moves to all those studios right?

Comment: Yeah, but don't worry I finally figured it out haha just took me a little bit to wrap my head around it all, I got stuck in the actual process of saving to the database but i've gotten there, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add Many studios to the one film, you could try to use a for looping.

Try to the code shown below in your action

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddStudiosToMovie(int  movieID, List<int> studioIdList)
    {
       for(int i=0;i<studioIdList.Count();i++)
        {
            var movieToStudio = new MovieStudios
            {
                MovieID = movieID,
                StudioID = studioIdList[i]
            };
            _context.Add(movieToStudio);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

    }
```